# how to create dynamic dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my view code:

```
<%= form_for(:offer,:url=>{:controller=>'offers',:action=>'create'}) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label "Select Category:" %> &nbsp;<%= f.select :catId_get, options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, "id", "name"), prompt: "Select Category"%>   

  <%= f.label "Select Menu" %> &nbsp;<%= f.select :catId_get, options_from_collection_for_select(@menus, "id", "menu_item_name"), prompt: "Select Menu Item"%>
```

In controller:

```
@categories = Category.where(:hotel_id=>cookies[:hotel_id_for_login_user])
@menus = Menu.where(:category_id=>params[:catId_get])
```

I am new in rails.I want to show respected menus on the menus dropdown when i select a category from categories dropdown.Please help me out.Thank you.

Comment: You have to use `onchange` method. Search about this. And a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690516/select-and-onchange-in-a-ruby-on-rails-form

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chained select box in Rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302470/chained-select-box-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 0):

This should be done dynamically through Ajax in such a way:

```
$(".category-select").change(function(){
  $.get( "/menus?category_id=1", function( data ) {
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
     $( ".menu-select" ).append( '<option value="' + val.whatever + '">' + val.whatever + '</option>' );
    });
  });
})
```

Or something along those lines.